# How to get the url serving the current js file

Tags: javascript, url, location

Suppose I have a site at www.somewhere.com that loads a javascript file called Test.js hosted at www.aplace.com. From within Test.js, how can I get the url www.aplace.com?

When I use window.location, I get the url of the site (somewhere.com) instead of the url of Test.js.

The reason I am asking is because I need to make a post request from Test.js to www.aplace.com/dirA/dirB/dirC/Test.js to www.aplace.com/dirD but I can't hardcode the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should be in `<script>` in `src='{THE_URL}'`, perhaps try scraping if API is not present.

Comment: Thanks, I ended using document.scripts and doing a search for the name of the file. Not the prettiest way, but it works very well.

Comment: Yeah that is a relatively better approach actually .` document.scripts` provides an array that one can refer to .